# Floating point invalid register access

Tags: sparc

While writing assembly code for SPARC V8 I get invalid fp register access.

I just want to know that why while writing double precision instructions operation only even numbered register should be used what is the problem giving odd-numbered registers?
Why we get invalid floating point register access error.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid floating point register access error can come: [SPARC Floating Point Instructions](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~atkinson/teaching/sp05/259/sparc.pdf)

1. If you did not include `-mhard-float` flag while compiling your code.
2. If you are using `double` precision floats then it has to even-numbered (SPARC V8) is a 32bit processor.